# Handle "add child to Gtk.Box" event

Tags: gtk, gtk3, pygobject

As I am aware, I can subscribe to Gtk.Box signal "add child":

```
box.connect("add", self.__add_to_switch_list)
```

which will be called when I add child by `box.add(child)`, and it's working.

But how I would do the same with `box.pack_start()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way.

---

`"add"` is only emitted when you call GtkContainer.add().
The first handler of this signal is subclass' method. For example, GtkBox does this :

```
/* gtk_box_class init: */
container_class->add = gtk_box_add;
...

static void
gtk_box_add (GtkContainer *container,
         GtkWidget    *widget)
{
  GtkBoxPrivate *priv = GTK_BOX (container)->priv;

  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (container), widget,
                      priv->default_expand,
                      TRUE,
                      0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I submitted a bug about that or adding this signal emission to GTK+. But it was closed / rejected . It's frustrating, because for dynamic widgets, which somehow visually change depending on number of childs, it's very desirable feature - to handle this in one place.

Answer (score 0):

In that [very same bug report](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues/1045), @ebassi tells you that you can connect to the child widget's `parent-set` signal. If you can't know when a parent has a new child, you can know when a child  has a new parent which is roughly the same thing.

Comment: Yes, this is workaround. But absolutely not the same. In terms of how things should be implemented and working correct. In case of box, I would have to handle this in just one place. And container is in response of emmiting this signal. If I working with "parent-set" child gets aware of parent. Or I have dynamically connect container method to "parent-set" of child, when child gets added to this container.

Comment: But no worry, I've just implemented own Box with "child-added" and "child-removed" signals.